# Polynomial approximation of a local stable manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Given:

$ \dot{x}=x+y^2 = f(x,y),$

$ \dot{y}=-y+4x^3+xy = g(x,y)$

Find a 4th order polynomial approximation for the stable/unstable manifolds at the fixed point $(0,0)$

**My attempt:**
I calculated the linear system with the associated eigen-value/vectors to find the stable and unstable subspace. For the stable subspace I found $\lambda = -1$ and $\vec{v}=(0,1)^T$.

I then attempted to solve $\triangledown H \cdot  F = 0 $ where $F=(f(x,y), g(x,y))$ and $H = x - p(y)$ and is a level curve along the flow.

I use a polynomial approximation $p(y)= a+by+cy^2+dy^3$ and determine $a=b=0$ by using that $p(0)=0, p'(0)=0.$

**And then I get lost.**

Answer (score 3):

Since $x=p(y)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
x'
&=p'(y)y'\\
&=\left(2cy+3dy^2+\cdots\right)\left(-y+4x^3+xy\right)\\
&=\left(2cy+3dy^2+\cdots\right)\left(-y+4\left(cy^2+dy^3+\cdots\right)^3+(cy^2+dy^3+\cdots)y\right)
\end{align}
$$
On the other hand,
$$
x'=x+y^2=cy^2+dy^3+\cdots+y^2.
$$
Now you must choose the constants $c$, $d$, $\ldots$ so that the two series are equal. For example,
$$
x'=-2cy^2+\cdots=(c+1)y^2+\cdots
$$
and so $-2c=c+1$, etc.